# extract twilio serverless function execution and gather verb date time

Tags: function, date, twilio

I have a gather verb in twilio studio,which will forward gathered digit to a function hosted in twilio's serverless environment.
Inside that function i need to know exactly when  the user pressed key. Is there any way to send date time as Parameter in gather verb's action url?

I know that,we can initiate current date inside nodejs  funcrion. But,what if the location of two server(twilio studio and seeverless  function) is in different place, which might initiate two different time

for example,lets say ,here i will be playing 20 audio/voice, I want user to pick one audio/voice.
option 1 :
so we can calculate the date/time when call initiated and when user pressed key to determine which voice user picked. i know we can judge by users' gathered digits,but that won't be useful in my actual use  case.

option 2 (my preference):
if it was possible to pass this value of k from loop to action url,so we will know which audio was picked

```
    var k;
    var gatherr = twiml.gather({
        action: `https://xyz.twil.io/xyz?currentChunk=${k}`,
        method: 'GET',
        timeout: 1

       });

    for (k = 0; k < 20; k++) {
       gatherr.play(`http://x.y.61.z/xyz${k}.mp3`);
      }

    return callback(null, twiml);
```

Comment: How do you know the date/time of the callers timezone?

Comment: @Alan   I have changed the question pattern ,please check now

Comment: I don't know which option is possible, I will change the question tag and title after solved method for future reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the Liquid Syntax parameter which provides Pacific time.

`Hello {{ 'now' | date: "%Y-%m-%d %I:%M%p" }}`

[Liquid Template Language](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/user-guide/liquid-template-language)

You can pass the result as a URL query parameter to your Twilio Function.